# Maven. Удалить неиспользуемые в runtime зависимости

Tags: java, maven, resources

В проекте есть несколько зависимостей. Однако две из них не используются в рантайме:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${annotations.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Зависимости лежат в папке /lib рядом с .jar'кой.

Необходимо из итогового дистрибутива исключить эти две и с ними **связанные** зависимости. Пытался делать через `<excludeArtifactIds>junit,annotations</excludeArtifactIds>`
Однако связанные зависимости таким образом не исключаются. Подскажите, как исключить основные зависимости и с ними связанные без явного указания на последние.

**pom.xml** - секция `<plugins>`:

```
        <!--region COMPILER-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--endregion COMPILER-->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.jar.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>dataConfigs/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>excelConfigs/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>excelTemplates/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>genToolsConfigs/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>

                        <mainClass>com.oaks.adnMaker.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.resources.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- копируем файлы ресурсов в ${distrib.directory} -->
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/conf</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>configuration/**</include>
                                    <include>dataConfigs/**</include>
                                    <include>excelConfigs/**</include>
                                    <include>excelTemplates/**</include>
                                    <include>genToolsConfigs/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <!--<excludeArtifactIds>junit,annotations</excludeArtifactIds>-->
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.javafx.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.oaks.adnMaker.Main</mainClass>
                <vendor>oak_ic</vendor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: а как собирается итоговый дистрибутив? это jar, war?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman jar+ отдельная папки с .jar'ками зависимостей и xml-конфигами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление `<includeScope>compile</includeScope>` в конфигурацию плагина должно решить проблему. Ну и явно указать scope первой зависимости. Например:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${annotations.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для каждой зависимости в **Maven** есть параметр **scope**. Scope может быть следующий:

- compile
- provided
- runtime
- test
- system
- import (Maven 2.0.9 или старше)

Если вы укажете **provided**, то эта зависимости и транзитивные зависимости не будут включены в итоговый артефакт.

Comment: Вот тут есть загвоздка. Для junit'a scope = test явно указан, при этом библиотека все равно добавляется.  Я так понимаю, проблема в конфиге плагина.

Comment: можете добавить минимальный pom.xml, что бы поэкспериментировать?

Comment: Добавил секцию `<plugins>` в вопрос